# Java: Daemon: thread.join() not finishing, when Exception was thrown before in one thread

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, daemon, runnable

I wrote a Java Daemon (a class which implements Daemon and Runnable) and now Im facing the following problem:

In init() I create a new thread. `Thread thread = new Thread(this);`
In start() I start the new thread. `thread.start()`.
In run I do a lot of various things.... then an exception occurs. (In my case: NullPointerException.).

What now happens is that I catch the exception in run() and I call stop(). There I call `thread.join()`, but this never finishes and InterruptedException is not thrown. How can I solve this problem?

In run() I do some things in a while-loop

```
private Thread thread;

public void init() {
    // if init is successful: this.thread = new Thread(this);
    // if init is not successful: call stop()
}

public void run() {
  try{
  // do something
  while (!this.stopping)
  {
      // do somthing
  }
  } catch (Exception e) {
      //do something and then call stop()
  }
}

public void stop() {
    this.stopping = true;
    thread.join(); // catch InterruptedException if it did not work
    // do some more things
}
```

and this is where the exception is thrown. stopping is volatile and I set it to true as soon as stop is called.

Thank you :-)

---

I got a lot of answers, but Im still not done with this problem. Everyone said I should not call stop() manually in my run() or init() Method. My problem is, that when an exception occurs in init() or run() I want to really *stop* the programm. To finish it, so that the programm is not running anymore. I dont know how I could achieve this without calling stop(). Simply waiting until run() is finished does not work, because it stops then and stop() is never called. Im also still not sure how to handle the exception problem.

Comment: Can you post a little bit more code? In fact I think you should try doing the same with a Callable http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html and a ExecutorService because you will be notified about Exceptions in you main-thread.

Comment: How else would I stop the daemon then?

Comment: @nano7 -- just return from `run()`.

Comment: And when init() is called and some of the things Im doing in init() fail - shouldnt I call stop() there either? Should I throw an exception or simply return?

Comment: Hm. If I dont call stop() manuelly in init(), if init() fails, I will never reach stop(), because I dont create a new Thread if init() fails. Should I throw an DaemonInitException instead?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `stop` is fine. People are warning you not to call `Thread.stop()`, which you aren't doing. What you **are** doing is calling `join` on the very same thread you want to join with - and that of course results in a deadlock. You have

```
catch (Exception e) {
  //do something and then call stop()
}
```

so that means you **are** indeed calling `stop` from the `run` method. That's wrong. It worked with no exception because then you didn't enter the catch-block. All you need to write in that catch block is `break;` to break the while-loop.

As an aside, you don't need a reference to the `Thread` at all -- that's just confusing things. If you ever need to access the `Thread` instance you `run` method is executing on, you can just call `Thread.currentThread()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I dont call thread.stop(), but stop(). The join() follows code which stops some things, for example a jetty server and resources used by what happened during run(). Maybe you are right and I dont need it as I simply have one thread?

Comment: You didn't post code so I'm just guessing at it. If you are calling `join` from the `run` method, then that doesn't make sense to me. If you call `stop` from some other thread, followed by `join` -- that does make sense.

Comment: I posted some more pseudo code. Maybe you can tell me if it makes sense now? The problem I now have: I dont call stop() manually in run(), but now stop() is never called if an exception is thrown in run(). And also, if I dont call stop() manually in init() if init() fails, stop() is never reached there too.

Comment: Thanks for answering. break; does not work, because the catch is already outside the loop. Normally it would finish the catch and then I thought the method would end. I wonder why stop() isnt called. I will try again.

Comment: If it's outside the loop then you don't need **anything at all**. You have already broken out of the run loop and you thread will die a natural death.

Comment: I swear, I tested it three times now - The method is finished, I see the exception that is catched in my log messages, but I never reach stop() unless I call it manually. I now that you must be right, but its somehow its not working. I really dont understand it.

Comment: No, of course you don't reach it, there is no magic here. The question is, why **would** you want to reach `stop` if the thread is already made to stop? If you have some cleanup code there, then you'll need to refactor. `stop` is a method strictly reserved to be called from other threads to signal your worker thread that it needs to end. If you want to release resources, then put that in the `finally` block of your try-catch in the `run` method.

Comment: Correct, I have clean up code. And I also want my program to finish. If stop() is not called, the process will never end until I call it from cmdl line (/etc/init.d/process stop). I must avoid this, I need to stop the program when an exception is thrown in run(). How would you do this? Thanks for your help. (Also I need to stop the program if init() fails and I dont know how to achieve this when I dont call stop() manually).

Comment: Your thread will definitely end as soon as your `run` method ends. That's all I can tell you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the program doesnt stop when I dont call stop(). Also, I still dont know how to solve the exception problem..

Answer (score 1):

You should never call stop. Just return from run or throw an exception from run and the thread will stop on its own. Thread.join is meant to be called from some thread that wants to wait for the daemon thread to complete. For instance, if the main thread received a message to shut down it might signal the daemon to stop (not by calling stop) and then use join to wait for the daemon to actually stop. There is a tutorial [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: well, as I have only one thread (=new Thread(this)) and did not set thread.setDaemon(true) for any thread, I dont need thread.join, correct? I wonder why it worked when no exception was thrown then...

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know exactly what is working wrong because your example is still only some of the code. I'm attaching pretty much the simplest possible multithreaded program I can write. The main thread prints "main" every 100 ms. The other thread prints "other" every 100 ms until stopped. The main thread stops the other thread after 10 iterations. Can you explain what this program doesn't do that you want yours to do? We can change it until it does that.

```
public class Main {

    private Thread thread;
    private Other other;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.run();
    }

    public void run() {
        other = new Other();
        thread = new Thread(other);
        thread.start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("main");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted waiting for sleep in main");
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    public void stop() {
        other.stopping = true;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted waiting for other to join main");
        }
    }

}

class Other implements Runnable {

    volatile boolean stopping;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stopping) {
            System.out.println("other");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted waiting for sleep in other");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What happens, if other.run() throws a NullPointerException? [My other.run() doesnt implement Runnable but is a method which can throw Exceptions] In my case thread.join() in stop() never returned. What I really wanted was to shutdown the entire program if an exception in run() was thrown (of course only after stop() and destroy() were called.) I tried to fix it with setting thread.join() to thread.join(3000). As this did not shut down the program, I use System.exit(1) now, which is working, but not very "nice". :-)

Comment: You can call Runtime.getRuntime().addShudownHook(). The thread you pass will be started after exit is called or any other time the VM would be expected to shut down. Shutdown is delayed until the thread completes.